# Same api endpoint for CRUD operations in Django generic apiview

Tags: django, api, crud, endpoint

I have been creating different api endpoint for different requests, for eg every single api for get, post, delete and update in generic apiview. But my frontend developer has told me it's a very bad practice and I need to have a single api for all those 4 requests. When I looked it up in the documentation, there is a ListCreateApiView for listing and creating an object, but I cant use it for delete and also for update. How can I include those two in a single endpoint. I don't use modelset view and also functional view. I mostly use generic api views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try rest framework's `ModelViewSet`?

i.e.:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
```

Which has all the mixins (CRUD) and you can inherit from it in your API view.
Or you can add these mixins based on your requirements:

```
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin
```

and you can inherit from each one of them seperately. For instance:

```
Class SomeView(CreateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

which has create and delete ability. You can also use mixins with `GenericAPIView`:

```
Class SomeView(CreateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    pass
```

Comment: I dont use modelviewset, I only use genericapiview and am comfortable with it. Is there mixins available for the generic api view or there is no option rather than to switch to modelviewset.??

Comment: I updated my answer... please take a look at last lines.

Comment: That means I can use mixins in generic view as well correct?? Also,please correct me, what mixins means is I can inherit those features if I use in my view class, that is why mixins are used, right??

Comment: Yes, you can use them in your generic views. Mixins are for improving your class abilities... You can not use them seperately... because they are dependent to other classes... that is why you have to inherit from `GenericAPIView` or `GenericViewSet` when inheriting from mixins.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can use generica api view and dont need to switch to modelview set.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to achieve this is by use of Generic views.

Simply start by adding this import to your `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import modelnameSerializer
from .model import modelname
```

Then here goes your generic class based view.
This view is for listing all items in your model of choice

```py
class yourmodelnameList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = modelname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = modelnameSerializer
```

This view is for updating, deleting and retrieving:

```py
class modelnameDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = modelname.objects.all()
    serializer_class = modelnameSerializer
```

In `urls.py` simply add:

```py
path('yourulchoice/',views.modelnameList.as_view()),
path('yourulchoice/<int:pk>/', views.modelnameDetail.as_view()),
```

Other things to note:

- django rest framework is installed.
- ensure `rest_framework` is added in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file.

The two url routes should be able to handle your CRUD needs.